# Is there a Visual Studio "Go to Partial" shortcut

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have an MVC project that uses a lot of Partial views, like in

```
@Html.Partial("_TasksGrid")
```

I happen to waste a lot of time looking for these partials and then finding that they are in the shared folder as opposed to the default folder and vice-versa.

My question is what would be the best way to navigate from one file to the other? Is there a shorcut/extension that can help me on this? I'd like to be able to put the cursor over the partial statement and press a shortcut that opens the partialview file.

Comment: Are you using [ReSharper](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)?

Comment: I am, but I would install an extension for this shortcut

Comment: With ReSharper, Ctrl+Left Click on _TaskGrid will open the file. Also, Ctrl + F12 while the cursor is on _TaskGrid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I got used to the "Edit.GoToAll" shortcut, but on my installation it had to be configured, I assigned Ctrl+T as my shortcut:

[image]

I can double click the partial name then hit Ctrl+T and the search will find the partial